# Why do we equate "newline" to an empty space in the argument newline = ' '?

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline

I've been going through the Codecademy tutorial on opening CSV files in Python 3.x and they give the following example, including a CSV file and an explanation paragraph, which I don't completely understand. Why do we equate newline to an empty space (i.e. `newline = ' '`) and what do they mean by the following?

> "The possibility of a new line escaped by a `\n` character in our data is why we pass the `newline=' '` keyword argument..."

Is there some technical reason for why we write `newline = ' '` specifically or am I missing some logical connection? Can the newline be equated to anything other than an empty space?

```
Name;Address;Telephone          
Donna Smith;126 Orr Corner Suite 857\nEast Michael, LA 54411;906-918-6560          
Aaron Osborn;6965 Miller Station Suite 485\nNorth Michelle, KS 64364;815.039.3661x42816
Jennifer Barnett;8749 Alicia Vista Apt. 288\nLake Victoriaberg, TN 51094;397-796-4842x451 
Joshua Bryan;20116 Stephanie Stravenue\nWhitneytown, IA 87358;(380)074-6173            
Andrea Jones;558 Melissa Keys Apt. 588\nNorth Teresahaven, WA 63411;+57(8)7795396386
Victor Williams;725 Gloria Views Suite 628\nEast Scott, IN 38095;768.708.3411x954
```

Notice the `\n` character, this is the escape sequence for a new line. The possibility of a new line escaped by a `\n` character in our data is why we pass the `newline=' '` keyword argument to the `open()` function.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `newline=' '` instead of `newline=''`?

Comment: The part about "a new line escaped by a `\n` character" makes no sense.

Comment: Keyword arguments are named arguments. The open function's newline argument can be None, '' (empty string), \n, \r, or \n\r. You can read about the open function (and other built-in functions) here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: If you want to quote content, use a `> ` prefix at the front of the line. That's much easier than bolding on the reader's eyes. Similarly, for multi-line content, use either triple-quotes gating above and below, or the `{}` button in the javascript editing UI.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out user2357112. It is two apostrophes. And thank you for the link to the documentation Schematic. I think I get a general idea of what's going on now.

Comment: It's because the `csv` module handles newlines in files it reads and writes its own way, so the documentation says to use `newline=''` so Python's own default newline handling is disabled when using the module to process files. This primarily to support newlines embedded in fields of logical "rows" of csvs.

Comment: See [this footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3) in the documentation.